# Cannot mount azure fileshare from kubernetes pod (works fine from local machine)

Tags: linux, azure, kubernetes, mount, cifs

I am running kubernetes in Azure where I have created a storage account and an azure file (file share)

From my local Ubuntu machine I can successfully mount the share with:

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs //mystorage.....windows.net/data /home/demo/azureshare -o vers=3.0,username=mystorage,password=-C5DM...tHRow==
```

But when I try to do the same from a running ubuntu pod I get:

```
$ kubectl exec diag-app-9d8fcc878e-5r6g -it bash
root@diag-app-9d8fcc878e-5r6g:~# sudo mount -vv -t cifs //mystorage.....windows.net/data /home/user/azureshare -o vers=3.0,username=mystorage,password=-C5DM...tHRow==
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=xx.xxx.xxx.xxx,unc=\\mystorage.....windows.net\data,vers=3.0,user=mystorage,pass=********
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

I have tried with `securityContext`:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
    ...
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
      containers:
      ...
```

But that gives:

```
Unable to apply new capability set.
```

So I have added:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
    ...
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0      
      containers:
        ...
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            add:
              - NET_ADMIN
              - SYS_ADMIN
              - DAC_READ_SEARCH
```

But still the same error. And  also tried:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
    ...
    spec:
      containers:
        ...
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
          capabilities:
            add:
              - NET_ADMIN
              - SYS_ADMIN
              - DAC_READ_SEARCH
```

Still same error.

The above is NOT something I am planning on doing in production I am just trying to understand why I cannot mount the share directly from inside a pod.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use the persistent volume?

Comment: Yes that works, but as I wrote in my post I am trying to understand why I cannot mount manually using cifs from a pod, I am not asking for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late. I had the same problem and had to deactivate appamor via

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    container.apparmor.security.beta.kubernetes.io/container_name: unconfined
```